Queries on Confidence Interval (IAL Q)
For (b), the official ans is 4x0.9^3x0.1 = 0.2916. But it seems they are treating like the probability that a particular interval containing the true mean is 0.9. However, 90% confidence interval should not be understood as the true mean has probability 0.9 to fall into the interval, instead should be on average, 90% of the intervals constructed will contain the true mean. So my thought is to do lim(n-->inf)((0.9nC3 x 0.1nC1)/(nC4)) and interestingly, the answer is also 0.2916. So I am thinking is it coincidence or my understanding to confidence interval is a bit incorrect. Thanks all!


What do you think the difference is between the two statements?  That is, if you believe "90% of the intervals constructed will contain the true mean", what do you think the probability of any particular interval containing the true mean is?

Each confidence interval has a $90\%$ probability of coverage; i.e., if $(L, U)$ is a $90\%$ confidence interval, then $L$ and $U$ are random variables satisfying $$\Pr[L \le \mu \le U] = 0.90.$$  Consequently, the probability that exactly $3$ of $4$ such intervals will contain $\mu$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n = 4$ and $p = 0.90$.
Equivalently, let $(L_1, U_1), (L_2, U_2), (L_3, U_3), (L_4, U_4)$ be four such interval estimates.  They are independent and identically distributed.  For each $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, define the Bernoulli random variable $$B_i = \mathbb 1 (L_i \le \mu \le U_i).$$  Then $B_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 0.9)$, and the desired probability is $$\Pr\left[\sum_{i=1}^4 B_i = 3\right].$$  This is entirely consistent with the frequentist interpretation:  $\mu$ is fixed, but the $(L_i, U_i)$ are random.

As for your solution, it's unnecessary to place the computation in the framework of an infinite number of intervals.  For instance, when we say that a coin has a probability $p = 0.75$ of landing heads, and we flip the coin $n = 7$ times, we can calculate the probability of obtaining exactly $X = 5$ heads without resorting to the computation of a limit or by thinking about a situation where we flip the coin infinitely many times, because the value of the success parameter $p$ already encapsulates that frequentist concept of how many successes we are expected to observe as a proportion of the total number of trials.

Thanks for your detailed explanation! But if this is entirely consistent with the frequnetist understanding, then why people always stated one misconception to let say 90% confidence interval is that we shouldn't say probability of the true mean lies in the interval is 0.9 as once the interval is calculated, then it either contains the true mean (Pr=1) or not containing (Pr=0).

@Psychomaths314 It's about the English language phrasing.  The statement "The probability that the true mean lies in the interval" implies that the mean is a random variable, because "probability" seems to attach to "true mean."  To avoid this association, we rephrase it as "the probability that the interval contains the true mean."  Switching the order around emphasizes that "probability" is attached to "interval" rather than "true mean."
